How "replaceable" is this Wifi chip after it has been SMD-soldered to the laptop's motherboard?
The laptop: HP Spectre x360 15tf-100
The problem: Wi-Fi module is dead. This laptop uses AX201D2W. It has the following package:


Replacement modules are easily available i.e. from Aliexpress.
Questrion is: How easily a module with the mount like this can be replaced? If I recall correctly, these types of mounts are soldered on using a reflow oven.Is it at all possible, or is it a 1-time mount and once it's dead the entire motherboard is to be replaced?

Is it replaceable? Yes
Can you replace it? Probably not
That's a pretty complex SMD rework task. Even worse than most other tasks because it's a whole own circuit under the RF shield on that little PCB.
There are people who can do that with the right equipment. The Problem is always heat managment. You need to get the right amount of heat to the right place for the right time while not heating up places that should not get it...
Even with professional equipment I'd say that this one is a tough nut to crack.
Additional question: how do you know it's the module and not anything else (like antenna?)
Suggestion: use an external solution (like USB Dongle) instead of risking destroying the Motherboard.

Antenna? It literally says "AX201D2W" right there on the package. (And it's the same package as every other "AX201D2W" module).

What they meant was: how do you know the module needs replacing, instead of, for example, the antenna or a different part of you motherboard?

When you use a module with an internal antenna, 'antenna' is not 'something else'

@david you see those two round thingies at the top of the module? Those are antenna connectors.
